# dynamic partial coloring a box

Tags: vb.net, label

I have a sql table that fills with times of working machine in a day
how can I create a box with time axis on it when machine works then related partial will be green and when machine is stop the related partial will be red ?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking for and you really need to do more work before posting a question here. SO is for questions of the form "this is what I want to do, this is how I tried to do it and this is how what I tried failed to do what I wanted" rather than "this is what I want to do, how do I do it".  You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That said, if what you want is just a bar that shows proportions using colour then you can simply use two `Label` controls side-by-side with appropriate `BackColor` and `Width` values.  Alternatively, you can use GDI+ to draw coloured rectangles in the appropriate `Paint` event handler.  That should be enough for you to go and do your own research.